# Viewable route returns 404

Tags: rest, jsp, jersey, jersey-2.0

When trying to access `/Example/Site` a 404 no found page will be shown, but the jsp is in `webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/`. Why is this not working?

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>jmattheis rest app</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.stackoverflow.jmattheis.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.servlet.filter.forwardOn404</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.mvc.templateBasePath.jsp</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/jsp</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.tracing</param-name>
            <param-value>ALL</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here the Resource:

```
@Component
@Path("Example")
public class Example {
    @GET
    @Path("/Site")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Response getSite() {
        return Response.ok(new Viewable("/test")).build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Have a look at the Jersey2 MVC documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/mvc.html)

> Jersey web applications that want to use JSP templating support should be registered as Servlet filters rather than Servlets in the application's web.xml. The web.xml-less deployment style introduced in Servlet 3.0 is not supported at the moment for web applications that require use of Jersey MVC templating support.

So you need to change your servlet to an filter to make it work.

It could be that this was not needed in the early versions of jersey 2, but I cannot find the older documentation for that so we'll never know.

Like this:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>jmattheis rest app</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>jersey-filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.stackoverflow.jmattheis.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.servlet.filter.forwardOn404</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.mvc.templateBasePath.jsp</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/jsp</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.tracing</param-name>
            <param-value>ALL</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>jersey-filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```